# POST method in Swift4 urlSession Decodable not working(What goes wrong here?)

Tags: swift4, urlsession, jsondecoder

I am trying to post 2 parameters (email: and password) to get a response from the server with detailed user information, I build API to handle this and get a good response using Postman, but when I tried to implement this with Swift4 new urlsession JSON decode and encode, it keeps failing and I got error on decoding the response data.
this my JSON response when using Postman:

```
{
    "error": "false",
    "message": "downloaded",
    "UserInfo": {
        "id": 5,
        "email": "abc@hotmail.com",
        "lastname": "Bence",
        "name": "Mark",
        "phone": "1234567",
        "add1": "333",
        "add2": "444",
        "city": "ott",
        "postalcode": "tttttt"
    }
}
```

My struct file:

```
import UIKit
struct loginPost: Encodable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let error: String?
    let message: String?
    let UserInfo: [UserData]

    }

struct UserData: Codable {
    let  id: Int?
    let email: String?
    let lastname: String?
    let name: String?
    let phone: String?
    let add1: String?
    let add2: String?
    let city: String
    let postalcode: String?


}
```

**My Function**

```
func downloadJson() {

     let url = URL(string: http://192.168.0.10/api/login_hashed.php)
    guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
    //POST Req


    var request = URLRequest(url: downloadURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let newpost = loginPost(email: "abc@hotmail.com", password: "123456")

    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newpost)

        request.httpBody = jsonBody
        print(jsonBody)
    }catch{
        print("some error")
    }


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, urlResponse, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print("something is wrong with url")
            return
        }

        print("downloaded..")
        do
        {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let downloaduser = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
            self.logmessage = downloaduser.message!

            print(self.logmessage)


            DispatchQueue.main.async {

               // self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("something wrong with decode")

        }
        }.resume() 
}
```

Comment: add your postman code and what error you are getting through URLSession

Comment: is your server is working fine?

Comment: Yes, the server is working fine and I can request a POST and get response accordingly form Postman. The URLseesion executed but the return data never decoded, it goes to catch { routine } too. the console print - "downloaded.." - after the Urlsession, and subsequently prints - "something wrong with the decode"

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out finally, thanks,.
I just want to mention the cause of this error and share my experience.
The main cause is the way you send JSON and receive the incoming response. you should know exactly how the data look in order to create your struct the acceptable way. 
My return data is just simple 2 line of text and array of text, my struct was:

```
import UIKit
struct loginPost: Encodable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let error: String?
    let message: String?
    let UserInfo: [UserData]

    }

struct UserData: Codable {
    let  id: Int?
    let email: String?
    let lastname: String?
    let name: String?
    let phone: String?
    let add1: String?
    let add2: String?
    let city: String
    let postalcode: String?


}
```

my mistake on line 18

```
  let UserInfo: [UserData]
```

it should be

```
let UserInfo: UserData?
```

without the square bracket.
one more important point, always try to catch the decode error and it's dicription by implementing }catch let JsonErr {, it will give you exactly why the decode not working.

in my case:

> downloaded.. something wrong after downloaded
>   typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [h2h.User.(CodingKeys in _E33F61CC43E102744E4EF1B7E9D7EDDE).UserInfo],
>   debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a
>   dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

And make sure to make your server API to accept JSON format application/json and
decode what you send in order to receive what you looking for;
php code service API

```
$UserData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest and easy way to decode the json.

**MUST TRY**

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let error, message: String?
    let userInfo: UserInfo?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case error, message
        case userInfo = "UserInfo"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserInfo
struct UserInfo: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let email, lastname, name, phone: String?
    let add1, add2, city, postalcode: String?
}
```

**After that in your code , when you get response from api then write**

```
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let obj = try! decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData!)
  Print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

   ### This Will work Are You Creating Model Is Wrong

   ```
   struct loginPost: Encodable {
       let email: String
       let password: String
   }

   struct Users:Codable {
       var error:String?
       var message:String?
       var UserInfo:UserDetails?
   }
   struct UserDetails:Codable {
       let  id: Int?
       let email: String?
       let lastname: String?
       let name: String?
       let phone: String?
       let add1: String?
       let add2: String?
       let city: String
       let postalcode: String?

   }


   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadJson()

       }

       func downloadJson() {

           let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.10/api/login_hashed.php")
           guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
           //POST Req


           var request = URLRequest(url: downloadURL)
           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
           request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
           let newpost = loginPost(email: "abc@hotmail.com", password: "123456")

           do {
               let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newpost)

               request.httpBody = jsonBody
               print(jsonBody)
           }catch{
               print("some error")
           }

           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, urlResponse, error in
               guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                   print("something is wrong with url")
                   return
               }

               print("downloaded..")
               do
               {
                   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                   let downloaduser = try decoder.decode(Users.self, from: data)

   //                self.logmessage = downloaduser.message!

   //                print(self.logmessage)


                   DispatchQueue.main.async {

                       // self.tableView.reloadData()
                   }
               } catch {
                   print("something wrong with decode")

               }
               }.resume()
       }


   }
   ```